# Chebyshev's inequality question

Tags: statistics

Question: Let $X$ be a random variable.  mean= 80 , std deviation ($\sigma$) = ? (unknown)

find std deviation for which $P(75 < X < 85) \geq 0.9 $

My approach is ..

$ P( |X - 80| \lt k*\sigma) \ge  1 - 1/k^2$
so $k^2 = 10 , k = 10 $

$80 - k \times \sigma = 75$

$80 + k \times \sigma = 85$

$\sigma = {\sqrt{(10) } \over 2} $

Did I do anything wrong ?

Comment: $X$ is distributed normally. Right?

Comment: @Oleg567: why should it be?

Comment: @ClementC. no-no, I'm wrong. It is not necessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

On the second line, if $k^2\geq 10$, then $k\geq \sqrt{10}$. From them, you can directly solve for $k\sigma = 5$, yielding (as you find, but an inequality is sufficient) $\sigma \leq \frac{5}{\sqrt{10}}=\sqrt\frac{5}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier. You need the inequality in the form
$$
P(|X-\mu|< \epsilon)>1-\frac{\mathbf{Var} X}{\epsilon^2}=0.9
$$ 
where $\epsilon=5$. Hence I get $\text{sd} X=\sqrt{\mathbf{Var} X}=\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$